# Make each UITableView cell open new views?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

How do you make each cell in a UITableView open a new view or .xib? An easy tutorial would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following links

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/

Write your navigation code here,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

Comment: Kinda incomplete, but using the tutorial- and other sites, I managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Hope Helpful for U...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
       if(indexPath.row==0)
       {
              //Open New View select on 1st row
       }
       if(indexPath.row==1)
       {
               //Open New View select on 2st row
       }

 }
```

Comment: Helped out more than the other one- but still incomplete.